# Fastest Gaussian Elimination Method?

Tags: matrices

I have this matrix and I want to know is there a method that I can always rely on to get the inverse without much trial and error.

The matrix is;
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: $A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det A} \text{adj} A$ where $\text{adj}$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

Comment: @NigelOvermars The problem with this is if you are finding, for example, the inverse of a $4\times 4$ matrix, you will have to find SIXTEEN $3\times3$ determinants.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Agreed. For much larger (square) matrices, it's far more efficient to use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I know, but you were asking for a reliable method, not a quick one.

Comment: @NigelOvermars The first word in the title of the question. :P

Comment: @alexqwx Damn, you're right. My mistake. I'll keep the comment just for some diversity. When dealing with $3 \times 3$ matrices I prefer the method I gave. Obviously, for larger matrices one needs the Gauss-Jordan algorithm.

Comment: @NigelOvermars For $2 \times 2$ matrices, your method is definitely the best. For $3 \times 3$ ones, I'd say it's a tie. But for $n \times n$ matrices, where $n>3$, Gaussian elimination is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **never** use trial-and-error for finding the inverse of a matrix.

General method: 
Say you've got a square matrix $A$, of which you want the inverse.
to find $A^{-1}, $start with the system $A \vec x=I$ (so start with the augmented matrix $[A \mid I]$, perform suitable row operations until the augmented matrix is in the form $[I \mid A^{-1}]$.

See this very-useful site:

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-row-operations-gauss-jordan.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always find the inverse of a matrix $A$, if it exists, using the Gauss-Jordan Algorithm. Start with $[A\,|\,I_n]$ (where $n$ is the dimension of $A$), and apply elementary row operations until you have $[B\,|\,I_n]$.

Then $B=A^{-1}$.

There is absolutely no trial and error involved and also this will tell you if $A$ is not-invertible --- if the reduced form does not contain $n$ pivots then the matrix is not invertible.